# Convex function and expectation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I was wondering: 
if f is a convex function and X a random variable, what does E(f(X)) = f(E(X)) implies?

Thanks a lot, David

Comment: In general, it does not imply much, **if $X$ is fixed**. For example for $X \equiv 0$, this is true for **every** function $f$. If you require the equality for **all** random variables $X$, things will of course be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If convex, the equality is $\geq$. If concave, the equality is $\leq$. If both a true, the function is both concave and convex. Therefore, it is linear (try showing this using definitions of convex, concave and linear). Also, I'm not sure, but I think such implication holds without the assumption that f is convex.

Comment: yes, Jensen's inequalities... You are totally right, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It implies that $x \mapsto f$ is a linear function.